# Updating Null values with non-nulls in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, sql-update

I'm trying to go through a table and update currently null info if there is a previous entry that was not null.  The code below is what I came up with but that's just updating every field so that every contact has the same fax number.  Does someone who is smarter than me know what to do?

Thanks for the help.

```
UPDATE dbo.AAASTA_CONTACT
SET 
CON_CSN = COALESCE(CRNT_RCD.CON_CSN, LST_RCD.CON_CSN),
CON_COMMENTS = COALESCE(CRNT_RCD.CON_COMMENTS, LST_RCD.CON_COMMENTS),
CON_EMAIL_ADDR = COALESCE(CRNT_RCD.CON_EMAIL_ADDR, LST_RCD.CON_EMAIL_ADDR),
CON_FAX_PH_NUM = COALESCE(CRNT_RCD.CON_FAX_PH_NUM, LST_RCD.CON_FAX_PH_NUM),
CON_HOME_PH_NUM = COALESCE(CRNT_RCD.CON_HOME_PH_NUM, LST_RCD.CON_HOME_PH_NUM),
CON_SEX_MF = COALESCE(CRNT_RCD.CON_SEX_MF, LST_RCD.CON_SEX_MF),
CON_PER_TITLE = COALESCE(CRNT_RCD.CON_PER_TITLE, LST_RCD.CON_PER_TITLE),
CON_WORK_PH_NUM = COALESCE(CRNT_RCD.CON_WORK_PH_NUM, LST_RCD.CON_WORK_PH_NUM),
CON_SUPPRESSMAILFL = COALESCE(CRNT_RCD.CON_SUPPRESSMAILFL, LST_RCD.CON_SUPPRESSMAILFL)
FROM
(
SELECT
CON.ALIAS_KEY, 
CON.LAST_UPD, 
CON.CON_CSN, 
CON.CON_COMMENTS, 
CON.CON_EMAIL_ADDR, 
CON.CON_FAX_PH_NUM, 
CON.CON_HOME_PH_NUM, 
CON.CON_SEX_MF, 
CON.CON_PER_TITLE, 
CON.CON_WORK_PH_NUM,
CON.CON_SUPPRESSMAILFL,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CON.ALIAS_KEY ORDER BY CON.LAST_UPD) AS UPD_RNK
FROM dbo.AAASTA_CONTACT CON
) CRNT_RCD
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT
CON.ALIAS_KEY, 
CON.LAST_UPD, 
CON.CON_CSN, 
CON.CON_COMMENTS, 
CON.CON_EMAIL_ADDR, 
CON.CON_FAX_PH_NUM, 
CON.CON_HOME_PH_NUM, 
CON.CON_SEX_MF, 
CON.CON_PER_TITLE, 
CON.CON_WORK_PH_NUM,
CON.CON_SUPPRESSMAILFL,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CON.ALIAS_KEY ORDER BY CON.LAST_UPD) AS UPD_RNK
FROM dbo.AAASTA_CONTACT CON
) LST_RCD
ON CRNT_RCD.ALIAS_KEY = LST_RCD.ALIAS_KEY
WHERE CRNT_RCD.UPD_RNK=1
AND LST_RCD.UPD_RNK>1
```

Comment: You're not connecting the select queries back up to the `dbo.AAASTA_CONTACT` row you're updating.

Comment: Any idea how to fix it? I've been staring at this for so long I can't see straight anymore much less see the fix.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what each field is and what the key is, but probably something like `WHERE CON.ALIAS_KEY = AAASTA_CONTACT.ALIAS_KEY` (you're probably better off specifying an alias for the update table (`UPDATE AAASTA_CONTACT ACON ...`) and using that `WHERE CON.?? = ACON.??`)

Comment: Yup it just hit me what you meant.  I'll mess with it a bit.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to write yourself an answer when you get it and accept it.

Comment: I'll be sure to yeah... just may take me all night.